# Why do I get a java.lang.Exception: No runnable methods exception in this test class?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, junit

I have implemented the following test class to test my service class of the REST api, which I have implemented. This is how my `ExpertsServiceTest.java` class looks like:

```
package demo;

import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.bson.types.ObjectId;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

import java.util.List;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ExpertServiceTest {


    @MockBean
    private  ExpertRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    private ExpertsServiceImpl service = new ExpertsServiceImpl(repository);


    Experts demoExpert = new Experts(ObjectId.get(),"Steve Jobs", "Enterpreneur",
            Availability.BUSY, Language.CHINESE);



    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception{
        ExpertsServiceImpl service = new ExpertsServiceImpl(repository);
        service.deleteAll();
        service.createExpert(demoExpert);

    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception{
        service.deleteAll();
    }


    public void testCreateExpert(){
        Experts expert = new Experts(ObjectId.get(),"Andrea Test", "Software Engineer",
                Availability.BUSY, Language.CHINESE);

        service.createExpert(expert);

        List<Experts> experts = repository.findAll();
        assertEquals(2, experts.size());

    }


}
```

However when I run the test I get the following error:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.6/bin/java -ea -Didea.test.cyclic.buffer.size=1048576 -javaagent:/opt/idea/lib/idea_rt.jar=43811:/opt/idea/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /opt/idea/lib/idea_rt.jar:/opt/idea/plugins/junit/lib/junit5-rt.jar:/opt/idea/plugins/junit/lib/junit-rt.jar:/home/andrea/Documents/repos/temp/demo_api/target/test-classes:/home/andrea/Documents/repos/temp/demo_api/target/classes:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa/2.2.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-aop/2.2.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-aop-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/5.2.3.RELEASE/spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.9.5/aspectjweaver-1.9.5.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-jdbc/2.2.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-jdbc-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/com/zaxxer/HikariCP/3.4.2/HikariCP-3.4.2.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jdbc/5.2.3.RELEASE/spring-jdbc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/jakarta/activation/jakarta.activation-api/1.2.1/jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/jakarta/persistence/jakarta.persistence-api/2.2.3/jakarta.persistence-api-2.2.3.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/jakarta/transaction/jakarta.transaction-api/1.3.3/jakarta.transaction-api-1.3.3.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/5.4.10.Final/hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.4.1.Final/jboss-logging-3.4.1.Final.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/org/javassist/javassist/3.24.0-GA/javassist-3.24.0-GA.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/net/bytebuddy/byte-buddy/1.10.6/byte-buddy-1.10.6.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/antlr/antlr/2.7.7/antlr-2.7.7.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/org/jboss/jandex/2.1.1.Final/jandex-2.1.1.Final.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/classmate/1.5.1/classmate-1.5.1.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/org/dom4j/dom4j/2.1.1/dom4j-2.1.1.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/common/hibernate-commons-annotations/5.1.0.Final/hibernate-commons-annotations-5.1.0.Final.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/jaxb-runtime-2.3.2.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/txw2/2.3.2/txw2-2.3.2.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/com/sun/istack/istack-commons-runtime/3.0.8/istack-commons-runtime-3.0.8.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/org/jvnet/staxex/stax-ex/1.8.1/stax-ex-1.8.1.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/fastinfoset/FastInfoset/1.2.16/FastInfoset-1.2.16.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-jpa/2.2.4.RELEASE/spring-data-jpa-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-commons/2.2.4.RELEASE/spring-data-commons-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-orm/5.2.3.RELEASE/spring-orm-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/5.2.3.RELEASE/spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-tx/5.2.3.RELEASE/spring-tx-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/5.2.3.RELEASE/spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aspects/5.2.3.RELEASE/spring-aspects-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-hateoas/2.2.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-hateoas-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/org/springframework/hateoas/spring-hateoas/1.0.3.RELEASE/spring-hateoas-1.0.3.RELEASE.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/org/springframework/plugin/spring-plugin-core/2.0.0.RELEASE/spring-plugin-core-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web/2.2.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-web-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/2.2.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/2.2.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/2.2.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/2.2.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-logging-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.2.3/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.2.3/logback-core-1.2.3.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-to-slf4j/2.12.1/log4j-to-slf4j-2.12.1.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-api/2.12.1/log4j-api-2.12.1.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.30/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.30.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/jakarta/annotation/jakarta.annotation-api/1.3.5/jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.5.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.25/snakeyaml-1.25.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-json/2.2.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-json-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.10.2/jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.10.2/jackson-annotations-2.10.2.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jackson-datatype-jdk8/2.10.2/jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.10.2.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jackson-datatype-jsr310/2.10.2/jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.10.2.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/module/jackson-module-parameter-names/2.10.2/jackson-module-parameter-names-2.10.2.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/2.2.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/9.0.30/tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-el/9.0.30/tomcat-embed-el-9.0.30.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-websocket/9.0.30/tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.30.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-validation/2.2.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-validation-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/jakarta/validation/jakarta.validation-api/2.0.2/jakarta.validation-api-2.0.2.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/validator/hibernate-validator/6.0.18.Final/hibernate-validator-6.0.18.Final.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/5.2.3.RELEASE/spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/5.2.3.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/5.2.3.RELEASE/spring-expression-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/com/h2database/h2/1.4.200/h2-1.4.200.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb/2.2.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/org/mongodb/mongodb-driver/3.11.2/mongodb-driver-3.11.2.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/org/mongodb/bson/3.11.2/bson-3.11.2.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/org/mongodb/mongodb-driver-core/3.11.2/mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-mongodb/2.2.4.RELEASE/spring-data-mongodb-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-test/2.2.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-test-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-test/2.2.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-test-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-test-autoconfigure/2.2.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-test-autoconfigure-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/com/jayway/jsonpath/json-path/2.4.0/json-path-2.4.0.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/net/minidev/json-smart/2.3/json-smart-2.3.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/net/minidev/accessors-smart/1.2/accessors-smart-1.2.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm/5.0.4/asm-5.0.4.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/jakarta/xml/bind/jakarta.xml.bind-api/2.3.2/jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.2.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/org/junit/jupiter/junit-jupiter/5.5.2/junit-jupiter-5.5.2.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/org/junit/jupiter/junit-jupiter-api/5.5.2/junit-jupiter-api-5.5.2.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/org/apiguardian/apiguardian-api/1.1.0/apiguardian-api-1.1.0.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/org/opentest4j/opentest4j/1.2.0/opentest4j-1.2.0.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/org/junit/platform/junit-platform-commons/1.5.2/junit-platform-commons-1.5.2.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/org/junit/jupiter/junit-jupiter-params/5.5.2/junit-jupiter-params-5.5.2.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/org/junit/jupiter/junit-jupiter-engine/5.5.2/junit-jupiter-engine-5.5.2.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/org/junit/platform/junit-platform-engine/1.5.2/junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/org/mockito/mockito-junit-jupiter/3.1.0/mockito-junit-jupiter-3.1.0.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/org/assertj/assertj-core/3.13.2/assertj-core-3.13.2.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/org/hamcrest/hamcrest/2.1/hamcrest-2.1.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/org/mockito/mockito-core/3.1.0/mockito-core-3.1.0.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/net/bytebuddy/byte-buddy-agent/1.10.6/byte-buddy-agent-1.10.6.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/org/objenesis/objenesis/2.6/objenesis-2.6.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/org/skyscreamer/jsonassert/1.5.0/jsonassert-1.5.0.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/com/vaadin/external/google/android-json/0.0.20131108.vaadin1/android-json-0.0.20131108.vaadin1.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/5.2.3.RELEASE/spring-core-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jcl/5.2.3.RELEASE/spring-jcl-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-test/5.2.3.RELEASE/spring-test-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/org/xmlunit/xmlunit-core/2.6.3/xmlunit-core-2.6.3.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/com/github/fakemongo/fongo/2.2.0-RC2/fongo-2.2.0-RC2.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/org/mozilla/rhino/1.7.7.1/rhino-1.7.7.1.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/com/vividsolutions/jts/1.13/jts-1.13.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/de/grundid/opendatalab/geojson-jackson/1.2/geojson-jackson-1.2.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.10.2/jackson-core-2.10.2.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/com/lordofthejars/nosqlunit-mongodb/0.7.6/nosqlunit-mongodb-0.7.6.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/com/lordofthejars/nosqlunit-core/0.7.6/nosqlunit-core-0.7.6.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/javax/inject/javax.inject/1/javax.inject-1.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/com/googlecode/lambdaj/lambdaj/2.3.3/lambdaj-2.3.3.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/cglib/cglib-nodep/2.2/cglib-nodep-2.2.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/org/jooq/joor/0.9.3/joor-0.9.3.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-mapper-asl/1.8.8/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.8.8/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/org/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/3.11.2/mongo-java-driver-3.11.2.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/com/foursquare/fongo/1.0.7/fongo-1.0.7.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-core/2.1/hamcrest-core-2.1.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-library/2.1/hamcrest-library-2.1.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.30/slf4j-api-1.7.30.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/org/projectlombok/lombok/1.18.10/lombok-1.18.10.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/de/flapdoodle/embed/de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo/2.2.0/de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo-2.2.0.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/de/flapdoodle/embed/de.flapdoodle.embed.process/2.1.2/de.flapdoodle.embed.process-2.1.2.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.9/commons-lang3-3.9.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/net/java/dev/jna/jna/4.5.2/jna-4.5.2.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/net/java/dev/jna/jna-platform/4.5.2/jna-platform-4.5.2.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.18/commons-compress-1.18.jar:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.jar com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter -ideVersion5 -junit4 demo.ExpertServiceTest,testCreateExpert

java.lang.Exception: No runnable methods

    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.validateInstanceMethods(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.collectInitializationErrors(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.validate(ParentRunner.java:416)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.<init>(ParentRunner.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:65)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:137)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner.<init>(SpringRunner.java:49)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.FilterRequest.getRunner(FilterRequest.java:36)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:49)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)


Process finished with exit code 255
```

Can someone indentify why this happens? I really cannot understand how to go about resolve this, as I am new to spring boot. Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: This has nothing to do with Spring Boot, but rather wrong usage of JUnit. You don't have an `@Test` annotation on the method that makes your test. Also the test doesn't make sense, you want to autowire something, but still create something manually. If you don't need spring then don't use Spring, but rather use plain Mockito for mocking and write aunit test, not an integration test!

Comment: Also I hope you see the error in your test class `setUp` method - first line `ExpertsServiceImpl service = new ExpertsServiceImpl(repository);` you are defining the service again in `setUp` method. You should be just reusing the one already defined.

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks I just got this error which is related to your comment 
`org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'demo.ExpertsServiceTest': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'service'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'demo.ExpertsServiceImpl' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}`Should I remove `@Autowired`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Test annotation is missing in your method.

According to me the easiest fix would be adding the same, as mentioned below.

```
@Test
public void testCreateExpert(){
        Experts expert = new Experts(ObjectId.get(),"Andrea Test", "Software Engineer",
                Availability.BUSY, Language.CHINESE);

        service.createExpert(expert);

        List<Experts> experts = repository.findAll();
        assertEquals(2, experts.size());

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

put @Test annotation on testCreateExpert() method.

Answer (score 0):

Prefixing test methods with `test` was a practice from JUnit 3.x. As you seem to be using JUnit 4.x, you no longer need that. However, you must annotate your tests methods with [`@Test`](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/latest/org/junit/Test.html):

> The `Test` annotation tells JUnit that the public void method to which it is attached can be run as a test case. To run the method, JUnit first constructs a fresh instance of the class then invokes the annotated method.

So, you'll have the following:

```java
@Test
public void testCreateExpert() {
    ...
}
```